# Distributing state to different components after login in React-Query

Tags: react-query

Once a user sends a login request, he receives data through a Graphql response including his settings, notifications and several other things that are distributed across some components. Currently I am storing a user's logged in state in a boolean and once that is true, I'm sending requests in each and every component that needs state from the server. This seems highly inefficient. Is there a way to achieve this by simply using the data that initially came in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that logging in is a mutation that returns the log-in data. I would have associated queries for /user/settings and /user/notifications, or maybe just a generic /user/data that gives you what you need about the user.

The mutation after log-in could then update that query by simply writing to the queryCache (see the [official docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses)). I would then just call useQuery on that query whenever you need to, and it will give you the data. if you don't want to make background refetches, set `staleTime: 0` and you will always get the data from the cache that you put there after your mutation. Extracting the useQuery call to a custom hook will make it as easy as saying:

```
const userData = useUserData()
```

wherever you need it.

As for the logged in state, some applications prefer to do the switch for logged-in / not logged-in right at the top to avoid this, something like:

```
isLoggedIn ? <MyAppForLoggedInUsers /> : <MyPublicApp />
```

Comment: I guess this is the solution. I couldn't however get this to work with nested arrays. I believe react query just isn't really optimized for graphql